# Does it make sense to have more than 2 worker threads on a machine with 2 cores?

Tags: java, multithreading

Imagine I have a collection of inputs (e. g. `Queue<ISomeInputDataItem>`). I have an `ExecutorService`, which has several worker threads that take input items from that collection, process them and put the results into an output collection. The order of items in both input and output collection is irrelevant.

If I run this code on a machine with X cores, is it correct that the number of worker threads in the thread pool should be X because

1. if it is less than X, then some cores will not be utilized during processing of the inputs and
2. the number of threads involved in a calculation is limited by the number of cores (if I have 2 worker threads and 1 core, they will end up sharing the time of that core)

?

Note: I'm interested only in Java thread pools under conditions given above (not in all possible general cases).

Comment: If your worker threads are doing (waiting for) any I/O and the work queue is filled quickly enough - then it could make sense to have more threads than cores.

Comment: Well.. All new machines use *HypeThreading*, so 2 physical cores=4 logical cores.. and the OS handles this (scheduling).. So you could also have 4 threads to make use of 2 physical cores..

Comment: @tbsalling No, the worker threads don't do any I/O. The just calculate something and put the results into the output list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the threads are CPU bound, that is, the code never waits on anything and the limiting rate is processing ticks, then using X is optimal.  Though using up to 2X ran just fine in my tests on Java 6.  (Even 4X was only a minor slowdown, but YMMV)

However, if the threads do much time waiting on disk or network IO, synchronized data structures, GPUs, etc. then you should use more than X so one will almost always be running even if several are waiting.

Comment: I'd like to add a caveat to this answer. Not all algorithms are inherently parallelizable. You may need some forms of synchronization at some points which reduces performance and may call for even more threads (because some may be waiting). Sometimes, a single-threaded solution may be faster than a multithreaded one, because the single-threaded program can run without locking.

Comment: @llogiq - I agree. Multi-threading will be very useful in cases where things can be done by 2 threads *independently*.

Comment: That's what the OP was describing: independent work items. (*"several worker threads that take input items from that collection, process them and put the results into an output collection. The order of items in both input and output collection is irrelevant"*) So the OP's algorithms are parallelizable

Comment: @llogiq Good point. I once was called in to analyze/troubleshoot a complex multi-threaded application and my conclusion was that they spent more time fighting over resources than they gained by working in parallel.  However, it sounds like OP has something that should run well in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @user949300 said,

If your program is running on a machine that has other runnable processes, then having more runnable threads *may* give your program a competitive advantage.  It depends whether the operating system scheduler policy gives a "fair share" to each *process* or a fair share to each *thread*.  If it's the latter, then the program with more runnable threads gets a bigger share.

Comment: Just curious - on what OSes does having more threads give you a competitive advantage?

Comment: I confess, my answer was hypothetical. I don't know the details of the various scheduling policies available in different operating systems.  If I was going to try by experiment, I would start with Linux because of how threads were fitted into that operating system.  (Under the hood, a thread is a special kind of "process")  But that was done quite some time ago, and there's been plenty of opportunity for them to have tweaked the scheduling policies since.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this code on a machine with X cores, is it correct that the number of worker threads in the thread pool should be X because

if it is less than X, then some cores will not be utilized during processing of the inputs and
the number of threads involved in a calculation is limited by the number of cores (if I have 2 worker threads and 1 core, they will end up sharing the time of that core)

---

This is perfectly correct. Except that, even if you have 2 cores and 2 worker threads, if the underlying data structure that they share for the Queue is ArrayList or as a matter of fact any contiguous block, they end up giving the same performance lag.

- This is because, data structure is loaded into memory as pages and in the case of contiguous block, once the queue is locked by one thread(by loading a page into memory), the other thread has to wait till it is released.

---